# Fortify Often Misused Authentication java.net.InetAddress

Tags: java, fortify

We are using Fortify for static code analysis. One of the issue reported by Fortify scan is "Often Misused: Authentication". The issue is flagged for all the occurrences of usage of one of the following methods from the class "java.net.InetAddress".

```
getAddress()
getByName(bindAddress)
getHostName()
getHostAddress()
getCanonicalHostName()
getLocalHost()
getAllByName()
```

What is the ideal fix for the same?

One possible way is suggested [here](http://www.hpenterprisesecurity.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/java/often_misused_authentication.html), i am not sure do we have any other ways to address this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Question is unclear, are you currently using details of the InetAddress for authentication, and are asking what kind of authentication you should use instead?

Comment: We have a Java process (Dispatcher) which will have reference to list of other servers which does the Authentication. Typically, client will refer to the Dispatcher and gets the list of Authentication servers to which the client will forward the authentication requests. Now, getHostAddress is used by Dispatcher to determine the IP address of the Authentication server which will be returned to the client. So, under DNS spoofing attack, the attacker could received the authentication requests which contains the credential. So, I am wondering how to handle this scenario.

Comment: @param83 Please share the example if you are able to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

The vulnerability is effectively just warning you as a developer not to trust the output from these. One effective way to determine whether a server is who they say they are is with SSL. 
It sounds like on your application that you are just getting a list of servers and forward authentication request to them. If the user is then connecting via SSL to authenticate with the machines, it probably shouldn't be a problem (as long as connection isn't allowed with self-signed certificates)